# Example Bruteforce Algorithm

Tags: c#

I am currently getting into Pentesting and Ethical Hacking to test website security.

 I would appreciate an example Bruteforce algorithm that is stored in a string. Not a dictionary algorithm, but a bruteforce algorithm. 
 For example, it tries the letter a. Then it tries the letter b, then it tries c and so on. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if i think that you should really come up with an own concept for this problem, i'll like to give you a hint how to do this.

**Disclaimer: this is the laziest, slowest and dirtiest approach possible but it gets its job done. NEVER EVER USE THIS FOR A REAL SYSTEM**.

**Programm.cs**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Brutforce b = new Brutforce()
        {
            Alphabet = new []{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
        };
        ICollection<string> vals = b.Calculate(3);
        foreach (var elem in vals)
            Console.WriteLine(elem);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Brutforce.cs**

```
internal class Brutforce
{
    public ICollection<char> Alphabet { get; set; }

    private ICollection<string> _calculate(int lenght)
    {
        if (lenght <= 1) return Alphabet.Select(a => a + "").ToList();
        ICollection<string> sub = _calculate(lenght - 1);
        return (from alpha in Alphabet from prior in sub select alpha + prior).ToList();
    } 

    public ICollection<string> Calculate(int lenght)
    {
        return Alphabet == null ? null : _calculate(lenght);
    }
}
```